# Focus a Control next to the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, focus

Suppose I have 6 controls on a WPF Window as follows:

```
TabIndex   |   Name of the Control
-----------+----------------------
   0       |       DataGrid
   1       |       Button
   2       |       ComboBox
   3       |       Button
   4       |       Button
   5       |       Button
```

When Datagrid has focus and if I Press <kbd>F5</kbd> or some other key which I wish, I want the focus to go on button with tabIndex = 1.

I can do it in simple terms like `Name_Of_The_Button.Focus();`.

Above I have given the example. In reality I don't know the control whose tabIndex is DataGrid's_TabIndex + 1. So, I can't use the above line of code.

Is there any other way that I can use to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are logical children of window's you can achieve that in following ways:

1. Hook `PreviewKeyDown` method on container of controls (say StackPanel).
2. Check if F5 key is pressed.
3. Loop over child of windows using `LogicalTreeHelper`.
4. Check tabIndex of child using `KeyboardNavigation.GetTabIndex(child)` method.
5. If true set focus on the child.

---

**Code**:

```
private void StackPanel_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.F5)
    {
        // Replace stackPanel with the name of your panel.
        foreach (UIElement child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(stackPanel))
        {
            if (KeyboardNavigation.GetTabIndex(child) == 2)
            {
                child.Focus();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```